# Partitioning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list

Please consider an array such as :

```
arrayAll = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Is there a package that enable to do partitioning to obtain :

```
arrayALLPartionned = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I can see how to do this with a for loop but would appreciate a "pre-made" function if existing.

Comment: Why do people prefer to call an external plugin function instead of writing 2 lines loop ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no pre-made function. Go with the for loop, but make it into a function too :)

Comment: @dystroy Because if you're already using the library anyway, a function call is clearer.

Comment: @dystroy: a) It's neater b) It may not even be a plugin; it could be built-in. For example, PHP's `array_chunk`.

Comment: Well it's kind-of like the functional tool "zip" to combine elements from separate arrays, but different. I'm not sure why any library would provide something like this; it's pretty specialized. (*edit* oh well beaten again by php :-)

Comment: Do you want to partition it by length or by total, by the way?

Comment: Python doesn't have it either, does it? People asked for this often IIRC

Comment: @minitech, basically I am trying to figure out the means I have to replace this function in Mathematica : http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html . In this  precise case by length. That is obtain subarray of size 3.

Comment: @Pointy So it's not really like zip at all.

Comment: @millimoose yes ... it's more like "take n from" I guess, which I agree has general utility

Comment: Just for fun I made a jsperf : http://jsperf.com/partition (I didn't check the other tested versions were correct). Don't take it too seriously though.

Comment: @dystroy I've updated your jspref with my answer. Just for fun too... not sure if my addition is a fair test!

Comment: @dystroy forgot the link sorry: http://jsperf.com/partition/3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), you can implement this with [`groupBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) and [`values()`](http://underscorejs.org/#values)

```
function partition(items, size) {
    var result = _.groupBy(items, function(item, i) {
        return Math.floor(i/size);
    });
    return _.values(result);
}
```

(This is less ugly [in CoffeeScript](http://jsfiddle.net/MW3BS/3/).)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MW3BS/

Comment: Note that Underscore.js now has a partition function: http://underscorejs.org/#partition

Comment: That partition function only splits the array in two.

Answer (score 24):

I think you will have to use a for loop, don't know of any inbuilt functions...

Try this function:

```
function splitarray(input, spacing)
{
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += spacing)
    {
        output[output.length] = input.slice(i, i + spacing);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Using `slice` can avoid one loop.

Comment: Removed the extra for loop - Thank for pointing that out

Comment: This is just as simple as the accepted answer, and doesn't depend on any external libraries. +1

Answer (score 19):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
function partition(array, n) {
  return array.length ? [array.splice(0, n)].concat(partition(array, n)) : [];
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `Array#splice` destructively remove the specified items, and returns them as the function value. **Note that this will destroy the input array, leaving it empty**.

Answer (score 6):

I've added this solution to [@dystroy's jspref here](http://jsperf.com/partition/3) and it *appears* to run twice as fast as the other solutions. **Edit: in Safari & Chrome but not Firefox**

Here is functional style solution to add to the mix of answers here.

It is a higher order function called `toPartitions` which returns a callback for underscore's reduce method or the native array reduce method.

Example usage:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce( toPartitions( 3 ), [] );
```

The function:

```
function toPartitions ( size ) {
    var partition = [];
    return function ( acc, v ) {
        partition.push( v );
        if ( partition.length === size ) {
            acc.push( partition );
            partition = [];
        }
        return acc;
    };
}
```

Like Clojure's [partition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition) it will not include a tail partition when there are not enough elements.

In your example you could do:

```
arrayALLPartionned = arrayAll.reduce( toPartitions( 3 ), [] ) );
```

If you don't want to use this with `reduce`, but just have a function which takes an array and partition size you could do:

```
function partition ( arr, size ) {
    return arr.reduce( toPartitions( size ), [] );
}
```

Therefore the solution would just be:

```
arrayALLPartionned = partition( arrayAll, 3 );
```

Comment: This is a cool solution. My only qualm is that this won't effectively handle scenarios wherein the input array is not evenly divisible by the partition size. For example, calling `partition(arrayAll, 4)` will return two partitions while the last value, `9`, is left absent. The fix for that would be inside the `if` conditional: `if (partition.length === size || index === list.length - 1) { /* ... */ }`
Of course, a more bespoke solution then would be to perhaps include an additional parameter (_e.g._, `withRemainder`) to indicate if the user wants a remainder partition in the output.

Comment: Here is a fixed version:

function toPartitions(size) {
  var partition = [];
  return function (acc, val) {
      partition.push(val);
      if (partition.length === 1) {
        acc.push(partition);
      }
      if (partition.length === size) {
        partition = [];
      }
      return acc;
  };
}

Answer (score 4):

One more solution, with no external library :

```
function partition(items, size) {
    var p = [];
    for (var i=Math.floor(items.length/size); i-->0; ) {
        p[i]=items.slice(i*size, (i+1)*size);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/xtHXZ/

Comment: thank you for your attention ! Would you mind explaining the use of "-->" ? I had never seen that syntax before.

Comment: That simply means "decrement i and compare the value after decrement to 0". It's just like doing `i--` and comparing afterwards as `i>0`. The intersting point in looping that way is that you don't have to evaluate the maximal range value more than once as `>0` can be computed in one operation. I don't say you really have to do it to make a fast code, it's not so important, but it's a habit I have.

Comment: excellent, i think it somehow correspond to my use of "reap and "sow" in Mathematica. thank you again.

Comment: This answer will truncate the results if it doesn't divide evenly into `size`

Comment: this solution will not consider the remainder: in your fiddle, you will miss the last element if you run it with 4 as size

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own prototype method to do this

```
Array.prototype.partition = function(length) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(i % length === 0) result.push([]);
    result[result.length - 1].push(this[i]);
  }
  return result;
};
```

If you prefer not to add to the native prototype, you can write a simple function:

```
var partition = function(arr, length) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(i % length === 0) result.push([]);
    result[result.length - 1].push(arr[i]);
  }
  return result;
};
```

You can [see it in action on this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPwpS/).

Comment: Never modify the prototype of a native object, this can cause compatibility issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype has an array.partition function as well as an eachSlice() function.  Sounds like eachSlice() is what you're looking for.  If you're using jquery, there's a plug in to be able to use prototype functions.  Here's a link to it... http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/implementing-prototypes-array-methods-in-jquery