# Split and group a collection of items in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to take a collection of records in Ember and split them into groups of some number, say 2.

So for example, with something like

```
{{#each node in model}}
  <span>node.name</span>
{{/each}}
```

I get `<span>thing</span><span>other thing</span><span>some thing</span><span>one more thing</span>`

I want to be able to pass node to something and wrap every 2 nodes with a div
something like `<div><span>thing</span><span>other thing</span></div><div><span>some thing</span><span>one more thing</span></div>`

In Ember 2.0 where most everything should be a component, where is the best place to handle this logic. Should it be a component or controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the principle that things related to display, or preparations therefor, belong in the component, I would prefer the component. You could do it like so:

```
partitions: computedPartition('model', 2)
```

Then in your template

```
{{#each partition in partitions}}
  <div>
    {{#each node in partition}}
      {{node.name}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Now it remains to write `computedPartition`, which is an Ember computed property:

```
function computedPartition(dependentKey, size) {
  return Ember.computed(dependentKey + ".@each", function() {
    return partition(this.get(dependentKey), size);
  });
}
```

There are different algorithms for partitioning. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345296/partitioning-in-javascript/26230409#26230409). Here's a short recursive one:

```
function partition(array, n) {
  array = array.slice();
  return function _partition() {
    return array.length ? [array.splice(0, n)].concat(_partition()) : [];
  }();
}
```

#### Going deeper

We can simplify (?) the above by introducing a higher-level computed property called `computedArrayInvoke`, which invokes a specified function on the array-valued property with the specified key, along with additional arguments:

```
function computedArrayInvoke(fn, dependentKey, ...args) {
  return Ember.computed(dependentKey + ".@each", function() {
    return fn(this.get(dependentKey), ...args);
  });
}
```

Now we can write

```
partitions: computedArrayInvoke(partition, 'model', 2)
```