# Display row in React using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

I want to display the items in a bootstrap row with 3 columns in each row.But with this code all items are coming in a single row.I want to display
`<div className="row">`
 when I have 3 items.

```
 renderItems:function(){
        var items = this.props.items;
        return items.map(function(item){
            return (
                 <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item}/>
              )
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first partition your `this.props.items` using the solution here [Partitioning in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345296/partitioning-in-javascript)

After that, the returned array will be partitioned

```
var partitionedItems = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]...]
return paritionedItems.map( (items) => <Row items={items} /> )
```

and your Row component

```
// RowComponent.js

renderItems: function(items) {
    return items.map(function(item){
        return (
             <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item}/>
          )
    });
},

render: function() {
    return (
         <div className="row">
             { this.renderItems(this.props.items) }
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: _.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2); using lodash